# How to set ID3D11Texture2D texels by hand?

Tags: directx-11, texture2d

Im going to make a raytracer, and I want to store my render data on a ID3D11Texture2D, so that I can display it or easily save to file using DX11, but I dont know how to initialize ID3D11Texture2D with the data I will have (probably an array of 32 bit RGB color)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either specify `pInitialData` in [CreateTexture2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you know the contents already at creation time, or call `UpdateSubresource` [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or `Map` [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/`Unmap` [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the texture to fill it with your raw values.